# export class that extends a function

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, export

I want to export a class that inherits from a specific parent 'dynamically':

```
// moduleA
import {localConstructor} from 'aPackage';

const globalCondition = () => {
  if (window.GlobalConstructor) {
    return window.GlobalConstructor;
  } else {
    return localConstructor;
  }
}

export default class extends globalCondition() {
 ...
}

// moduleB

import Module from 'moduleA';
const m1 = new Module();  // use local constructor

window.GlobalConstructor = ...;
const m2 = new Module(); // use global constructor
```

However, `globalCondition` is only called at 'export' time and therefore I can not adjust the type of the object on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If exported class is supposed to depend on some dynamic condition, it should be factory function:

```
// moduleA
import {localConstructor} from 'aPackage';

export default () => {
  return class extends (window.GlobalConstructor || localConstructor) {...}
}

// moduleB

import moduleFactory from 'moduleA';

const Module = moduleFactory();
const m1 = new Module();  // use local constructor
```

Communicating between ES modules through `window` isn't a good practice. Instead of setting `window.GlobalConstructor = ...` a constructor could be passed to a function; this is a regular mixin recipe:

```
// moduleA
import {localConstructor} from 'aPackage';

export default (Constructor = localConstructor) => {
  return class extends Constructor {...}
}

// moduleB

import moduleFactory from 'moduleA';

const Module = moduleFactory(...);
const m2 = new Module(); // use global constructor
```